# How to get location based Admin views in Django?

Tags: python, django, api, django-admin, django-project-architect

I am new to Django and I am working on online food ordering system. I am going to use Django for backend. 
I am not sure about how to show various admin views based on different restaurants suppose I have restaurants in 3 three cities A,B and C. How to implement different admin views for A,B and C so that each restaurant can view it's order in it's admin views.

Also how to make driver view and how to separate delivery boy login and how to assign ordered to him.

Also which API to use to detect location and assign order. 
Anyone know how to complete this project using Django?

Answer (score 0):

You can make choices for a field in django model and provide functionaltity accordingly. Use if statement for that. For assigning order use foreign keys. GeoIP is package for detecting GPS location.